# Is it possible to add the Android wearable apk as a separate .obb expansion?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, wear-os, apk-expansion-files

I am building a Wearable version of my Unity3d game for Android Wear, and everything works fine when building from Android Studio, however the resulting dual APK is > 50mb. I have researched using expansion files, but it seems to me the simplest course of action is to add the Wearable APK as an expansion file. Has anyone successfully tried this? Is it possible to load the wearable APK separately and still install on the watch? Thanks.

Comment: Rather than an expansion, have you looked into [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)?

Comment: I have looked into this, but it doesn't solve the fundamental problem, which is that our Android Wear version would still be > 50mb